# vba write numeric data as text into excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I am writing data into an excel spreadsheet.  The data comes from an Access Database.  Code like the line below works:

```
xl.cells(5,5)="joe"
```

but code like the line below does not:

```
 xl.cells(5,5)="1/2CD438"
```

I get an error like "Application defined or object defined error"
I think Excel is trying to do a calculation, and the calculation fails.  All I really want is the text string.

I've tried formating the column like

```
columns(1).NumberFormat="@"
```

, but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: try putting a `'` at the start of the value like `xl.cells(5,5)="'1/2CD438"`

Comment: The `'` will do, but setting NumberFormat to @ beforehand should work just as well. And I do not get any error when I try `xl.cells(5,5)="1/2CD438"` with a cell in 'general' format. Sounds odd.

Comment: Tried `Cells(5,5).Value` (or value2)?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Like @KekuSemau I just tried `xl.Cells(1, 1) = "1/2CD438"` and got no error under Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.  I had tried several of your ideas without success.  As it turns out I was using variables to determine the exact row, column as:

xl.cells(NextRow, Col) = ars!PartNo

By simply replacing NextRow with an integer, the code worked.  Replaced the integer in the test with NextRow, and the code ran.  I suspect a misspelling or something, but couldn't see it looking at the code.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Check the top of the VBA module containing your code. If you don't see `Option Explicit` as the first (or perhaps the second) line then put it in there at the very top. Using that option will save you a lot of consternation in the long run.